# Is regex matching more efficient than checking for a key in an object as a set?

Tags: javascript, regex

So, in JavaScript, I need to check have a simple, fast way to check if a string of length 1 belongs to some set of characters, such as is it a string character for a javascript identifier?

I wrote the following test:

```
//performance test for matching

var re = /[a-zA-Z$_]/;

console.time("regex");
for(var i=0;i<100000;i++) re.test("_");
console.timeEnd("regex");

var objs = {"_":true, 0:true, 1:true, 2:true, 3:true, 4:true, 5:true, 6:true, 7:true, 8:true, 9:true, a:true, b:true, c:true, d:true, e:true, f:true, g:true, h:true, "i":true, j:true, k:true, 
  l:true, m:true, n:true, o:true, p:true, q:true, r:true, t:true, $:true
};


console.time("objcheck");
for(var i=0;i<100000;i++) "_" in objs;
console.timeEnd("objcheck");
/*
regex: 10ms
objcheck: 1ms
*/
```

Something strange here is, on a consistent basis, the checking for a key in an object thats defined as a set seemed to be far faster than doing a one character regex match. Why is this the case? Shouldn't the regex be faster here?

Comment: What makes you think it should?

Comment: Your microbenchmark is quite flawed, don't trust it. Benchmark your real application using the two different approaches.

Comment: Have you considered using a `Set`?

Comment: Be very careful about using a naive approach to benchmarking. However I am also surprised you would expect regex processing to be faster than an optimised name lookup.

Comment: I thought that for character ranges a regex would simply use a jumptable under the hood in the assembly side, if were talking about the V8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your data, no; A regex is not faster than a set.

This is because a regex needs to be compiled before it can be run. While you could improve these numbers by pre-compiling the regex, a regex is more general purpose than a set or a plain old loop, so fewer optimizations can be made to them by the interpreter.